# I am writing a React app and when I run it I get the following error so it does not even open the browser even though

Tags: reactjs

C:\Users\משתמש\Desktop\Project #3\client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at Object.getBuildInfo (C:\Users\משתמש\Desktop\Project #3\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:110534:21)
at readBuilderProgram (C:\Users\משתמש\Desktop\Project #3\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:123290:28)
at Object.createWatchProgram (C:\Users\משתמש\Desktop\Project #3\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:123446:26)
at Object. (C:\Users\משתמש\Desktop\Project #3\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\typescript-reporter\reporter\TypeScriptReporter.js:304:59)
at Generator.next ()
at C:\Users\משתמש\Desktop\Project #3\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\typescript-reporter\reporter\TypeScriptReporter.js:8:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (C:\Users\משתמש\Desktop\Project #3\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\typescript-reporter\reporter\TypeScriptReporter.js:4:12)
at Object.getIssues (C:\Users\משתמש\Desktop\Project #3\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\typescript-reporter\reporter\TypeScriptReporter.js:227:28)

Comment: the Title of your question is long but still ends somehow surprisingly unfinished _"... even though"_ On the other hand there is no text in the Question body except the unformatted Syntax Error output, perhaps parts of the story got unintentionally lost?

Comment: I wanted to write that I had run several times before without any problem and then the problem appeared even though I did not make any change

Comment: I'd probably keep the Title short and yet descriptive, like the title of a Book. And put the longer Details description story into the body of the Question, so that Readers might enjoy reading :)

Comment: You could format the _"SyntaxError: ..."_ part by adding angle bracket(s) > in front of the line(s) for better readability if you like

Comment: Currently SO does not let me edit your question, "Suggested Edits Queue is full", but you as the Question owner should be able I'd guess

Comment: I did not quite understand what I need to upload to better explain the error ... this is just the first time I upload a question... its look like the problem is in node modules ...but i have no idea about it

Comment: I'd post the `[reactjs]` script itself, or the relevant part(s) of it; the `data`, i.e. the invalid `Json` that is mentioned in the `SyntaxError` output: _"Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at"_

Comment: Sometimes mentioning the "steps to reproduce" can be useful, and the observed behavior, as opposed to the expected behavior.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276266/how-to-edit-a-previously-asked-stack-exchange-question

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Basically formatting Code works easily by adding a line containing only three back-ticks ``` at the top of the Code, and another line with just three ``` back-ticks added at the bottom of the Code